# Swift 3 Core Data - Cannot Save Relational Value

Tags: core-data, xcode8

I'm getting an error when I simply try to save data. Here is what I'm doing...

1) First I Fetch using a Category object:

```
let categories: NSFetchRequest<Categories> = Categories.fetchRequest()
categories.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id==%@", '25')
var category = try managedObjectContext.fetch(categories)[0]
```

2) Then I set the values on a new Subcategories object:

```
let subcategory = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Subcategories", into: managedObjectContext) as! Subcategories
subcategory.text = "Some text..."
subcategory.categories = category
```

3) Lastly I save:

```
managedObjectContext.save()
```

***** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]'**

Category is not nil though because I can print it immediately before saving. I think there is a problem with the managedObjectContext.

Comment: Did you check types of subcategory.categories and category? What type is your subcategory.categories?

Comment: Did you use NSManagedObjectSubclassing?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The problems was on the parent entity "categories". I had checked a box to set those to "ordered", which for some reason caused this weird error. What specifically was happening was the categories fieldof the object returned from my query was always nil, always.